# How to enable reply button on mostly deeply-nested comments?

Tags: comments, admin, threading

I have a blog on wordpress.com, using the [Twenty Twelve](https://wordpress.org/themes/twentytwelve/) theme.

## Background

In my experience, on wordpress blogs with nested comments, the reply buttons only show on individual comments when their nesting level is above the maximum depth allowed. However, one can reply directly to any comment at any level when using the wordpress Android app. This can also be done via webgui by clicking the "reply to" link in a notification email, or by custom forming a ?replytocom URL.

Depending on their personal app/email settings, users may get notified of any replies to their comments.

If a user replies to a comment that was already at the deepest nesting level allowed, then the notifications operate as usual, but it will be displayed as a peer of its parent comment.

## Questions

To start with, is all of the "background" above correct?

Is there a way to enable the reply buttons on all levels of comments?

If not, is there a known reason for the discrepancy in the interfaces?

Thanks.

Comment: We can't help with wordpress.com - that's a 3rd party hosted service, and you're very limited by what code you can modify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you have a blog on WordPress.com, so you can't change any code to make this happen.

> To start with, is all of the "background" above correct?

Yes.

> Is there a way to enable the reply buttons on all levels of comments?

No, not on WordPress.com. If you self host a site, there are ways to do this.

> If not, is there a known reason for the discrepancy in the interfaces?

No, there isn't. [Here's a bug](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/13792) that has been filed and probably would be fixed. You should add your observations there.

Comment: Do you know what "comment admin" means in the bug you linked? Is that the software module that handles the comments?

Comment: It means the *wp-admin/edit-comments.php* of a blog. You can approve, delete and reply to comments from there.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. In the case of that bug, I think it's related to the features I'm talking about, but probably just a different way that admins access the same thing. In any case, your answer was informative, and you pointed me to the developers bug/feature tracker, so that's all quite helpful. I'll follow up there.